# Date parsing help in R: Error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`: ! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Tags: r, parsing, timedate

I'm trying to parse a date, but returning error or NAs.
I'm using googlesheets4 to import a google sheet. One of the columns has dates in a %d/%m/%Y format, with no leading 0s. Ex: 1/5/2022. I suspect the lack of leading 0s is the problem, but I don't have the option of reformatting the data in the google worksheet (it's a shared document I don't have permision to edit).

My goal is to join this dataframe to another dataframe to compare the dates in both. Thanks in advance!

So far I've tried:

1. Importing as date with read_sheet. Upon import looks ok, it is recognized as a Date type column and looks like this upon viewing the dataset: "2022-05-01". After joining with the second dataframe, I compare it with the other date and get the following error:

*Error in `filter()`:

ℹ In argument: `a_datetime > date`.
Caused by error in `as.POSIXlt.character()`:
! character string is not in a standard unambiguous format*

Code as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(googlesheets4)

first_df <- read_sheet(googleworksheet_id,
                     sheet = sheet_name, 
                     col_types = "iccD") %>% 
  drop_na(date)

second_df <- read_csv("second_df.csv", col_types = cols( a_timedate = col_datetime(format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), id = col_character()) %>% 
  left_join(first_ds , by = id ) %>% 
  filter(a_datetime > date)
```

2. Importing as character with read_sheet and then converting to date, which brings up the following warning:

*All formats failed to parse. No formats found.*

Code as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(googlesheets4)

first_df <- read_sheet(googleworksheet_id,
                     sheet = sheet_name, 
                     col_types = "iccc") %>% 
  drop_na(date) %>% 
  mutate(date = as_datetime(date, format = '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Lubridate provides list of date parsers, have you tested `dmy`?  `lubridate::dmy("1/5/2022")`

Comment: Tried as follows, but resulted in all NAs:  `first_df <- read_sheet(googleworksheet_id,
                     sheet = sheet_name, 
                     col_types = "iccc") %>% 
  drop_na('date') %>% 
  mutate('date' = dmy(date))`

Comment: What exactly does the data look like after `read_sheet`? Can you provide the `dput()` for the first few rows so we can run and test it ourselves?

Comment: dput looks like this after read_sheet with the column as character: `structure(list(id = c("407", "428", "427", "443", "423", "438"), 
date = c("25/7/2022", "25/7/2022", "26/7/2022", "26/7/2022", "27/7/2022", "27/7/2022")),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))` and like this with the column as date: `structure(list(id = c("407", "428", "427", "443", "423", "438"),
date = structure(c(19198, 19198, 19199, 19199, 19200, 19200), class = "Date")),
row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))`